# Laravel View Composer duplicating SQL queries for every view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I need to access some data (User details) in most views. What I have done:

I created ComposerServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer(
            ['includes.header','profile'],
            'App\Http\ViewComposers\CustomerComposer'
        );

    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Created CustomerComposer class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Modules\Customers\Entities\CustomerDetail;

class CustomerComposer
{
    public $customer = [];

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $user = Auth::guard('customer');

        $this->customer = CustomerDetail::where('user_id',$user->id())->first();

        $view->with( 'customer', $this->customer );
    }
}
```

Everything works but when I look at Debug bar it shows me same queries excecuted per view, so for example if I define ['includes.header','profile'] Same SQL will be excecuted twice if ['includes.header','profile','something_else'] 3 times and so on...

In this case query's is

```
select * from `customer_details` where `user_id` = '1' limit 1
select * from `customer_details` where `user_id` = '1' limit 1
```

If I provide wildcard in

```
view()->composer(
            ['*'],
            'App\Http\ViewComposers\CustomerComposer'
        );
```

It will generate 23 queries! I missed something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I think I found solution. In ComposerServiceProvider class:

```
/**
* Register the application services.
*
* @return void
*/
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton(\App\Http\ViewComposers\CustomerComposer::class);
}
```

That it.

In Laravel Docs

> Registering A Singleton
>
> Sometimes, you may wish to bind something into the container that
>   should only be resolved once, and the same instance should be returned
>   on subsequent calls into the container:

Answer (score 1):

Per the manual at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers:

"View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view **each time that view is rendered**, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location."

(emphasis mine)

In this case:

```
    view()->composer(
        ['includes.header','profile'],
        'App\Http\ViewComposers\CustomerComposer'
    );
```

you're attaching the `includes.header` view and the `profile` view, which I guess includes the `includes.header` view. So, since the composer is executed when the view is rendered, it'll execute twice, one when rendering of the `profile` view and again another when rendering the `includes.header` view.

Comment: I understand that, but what is most efficient way to pass data from Model to all views? I though this implementation is made for this, I must be missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use config here to resolve multiple times query run issue for view compose. For example show below code.

public function compose(View $view)
{

```
if(!Config::has('composeVars')) 
{
    Config::set('composeVars') = [
      'users' => User::all();  
    ];
}

$view->with('*', Config::get('composeVars'));
```

}